# characterization of a normal measure

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Problem 10.5 from *Set Theory*, Jech: A measure $U$ on $\kappa$ is normal if and only if the diagonal function $d(\alpha)=\alpha$ is the least function $f$ with the property that for all $\gamma<\kappa$, $\{\alpha:f(\alpha)>\gamma\}\in U$.

(Here, for $f$ and $g$ in $\kappa^\kappa$, let $f\equiv g$ if and only if $\{\alpha<\kappa:f(\alpha)=g(\alpha)\}\in U$. We define $<$ on the equivalence classes by letting  $f<g$ if and only if $\{\alpha<\kappa:f(\alpha)<g(\alpha)\}\in U$. A normal measure is a nonprincipal $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter closed under diagonal intersections.)

For the $\Rightarrow$ direction, to show that $d$ is the least function with such a property, we need to show $d<f$ for all such functions $f$, i.e. $\{\alpha<\kappa:d(\alpha)<f(\alpha)\}=\{\alpha<\kappa:\alpha<f(\alpha)\}\in U$. How do I show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otherwise the complement  $\{\alpha<\kappa:f(\alpha)\le\alpha\}\in U$.  Since we have $\{\alpha<\kappa:f(\alpha)=d(\alpha)=\alpha\}\not\in U$, it follows that $\{\alpha<\kappa:f(\alpha)<\alpha\}\in U$.  Now you can apply normality and get that $f$ must be constant (and hence less than $d$) on some measure one set.

Edit:

It's easy to get lost in all these set definitions, but really the line of reasoning is as follows: $d$ is almost always bigger than each individual ordinal.  If $f$ is less than $d$, then $f$ is almost always regressive and hence almost always constant.  But $d$ is almost always bigger than that constant value, so $d$ is almost always bigger than $f$.

Explicitly, once we have $d>f$, we have $\{\alpha<\kappa:d(\alpha )>f(\alpha )\}\in  U$.  This is the same set as $\{\alpha <\kappa:\alpha >f(\alpha )\}\in  U$.  What this means is that $f$ is regressive on a set in $U$.  Normality implies $f$ is constant on a(nother) set in $U$, i.e. for some $\beta $, $\{\alpha <\kappa:f(\alpha )=\beta \}\in U$.  This will imply $f<d$, a contradiction.

Consider all the ordinals after $\beta$, $\{\alpha <\kappa:\beta <\alpha \}$, i.e. $\kappa\setminus (\beta +1)$. This set is in $U$ by $\kappa$-completeness (and non-principality: each $\{\alpha\}\not\in U$ so that the union $\beta+1=\bigcup_{\alpha\le\beta}\{\alpha\}\not\in U$ and hence the complement $\kappa\setminus(\beta+1)\in U$).  This set is equal to $\{\alpha <\kappa:\beta <d(\alpha )\}\in U$.  Thus we can intersect to get another set in $U$:
$$\{\alpha <\kappa:f(\alpha )=\beta \}\cap\{\alpha <\kappa:\beta <d(\alpha )\}\in  U\text{.}$$
The set above is a subset of $\{\alpha <\kappa:f(\alpha )<d(\alpha )\}\in U$ so that $f<d$.

Comment: Apply normality and get that $f$ must be constant on some set in $U$ - then why does it follow that $f$ is less than $d$?

Comment: @user500144 Recall the property of $d$ you stated above: for all $\gamma<\kappa$ (e.g. the usual value of $f$), $\{\alpha<\kappa:d(\alpha)=\alpha>\gamma\}\in U$.  It follows that $\{\alpha<\kappa:d(\alpha)>f(\alpha)\}\in U$ and hence $d>f$.

Comment: I don't really see it. To show $d<f$, we start by assuming for a contradiction that $d>f$. Then we can get $\{\alpha<\kappa: d(\alpha)>f(\alpha)\}\in U$ by definition. I don't know where normality comes into play and what contradiction we're getting.. Would you mind just writing a full answer? I'm really new to this.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. It makes more sense now. And by '$d$ is almost always bigger than each individual ordinal' you mean for all $\gamma<\kappa$, $\{\alpha<\kappa:d(\alpha)>\gamma\}\in U?$ (and similarly for the others where you mentioned 'almost always' you mean the set of $\alpha$'s such that the propery holds belongs to $U$?)

Comment: By the way, it seems that the $\Rightarrow$ direction can be proved without $U$ being a normal measure.. is that right? (In the proof of Theorem 10.20 in Jech, we start with $U$ being just a $\kappa$-complete nonprincipal ultrafilter, and then it's mentioned 'Such functions exist: for instance, the diagonal function $d(\alpha)=\alpha$ has this property')

Comment: @user500144 Yes, "almost always", "almost everywhere", "measure one",  "large" and a bunch of other terms are used in that way.  An ultrafilter makes the usually vague notion precise.  Also, while such functions will exist, normality is required for $d$ to be minimal.